# How to control the data in lightswitch application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-lightswitch

We are using a table `dbo.Events` which has **year** column in it. Recently we are unable to find 2014 year data in it. However I can find it in `SQL Server database` and able to find other years like 2013, 2015 on the screen.

I am assuming the application has the capability to drop the last year i.e 2014 data .

How can I debug it? Please let me know If I can provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug by asking your dataworkspace for your data 
(on any screen)

```
   var GetAllMyEventsData =  Dataworkspace.ApplicationData.Events.execute().tolist();
```

Loop this list, if for any reason 2014 did not show up, in this list it wil.

Once you know for sure it can be accessed, double check your visual collection for filters / pre proccess filters